# Am I doing this right with a Gaussian Distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have the following code in MATLAB, which I believe calculates the probability of a certain point (p) in the normal distribution. I know sigma (variance) and mu (mean) based on calculations.

```
f = (1/sqrt(2 * pi * (sigma(x, y))^2)) * exp(-((p - mu(x, y))^2)/(2 * (sigma(x, y))^2));

if f >= P
    cloud = false;
else
    cloud = true;
end
```

My question is this, if p = 0.1 and P = 0.9, will my result be that there is at least a 90% chance that p will be less than or equal to 0.1?

This is for cloud cover, so I am looking at whether there will be at least a 90% chance that cloud cover will be 10% or less.

Comment: The function is [probability density function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok/4223#4223) not a cumulative distribution function so it does not answer the question you ask.

Comment: Suggestion on a function to use?

Comment: You are looking for [quantile function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212813/help-me-understand-the-quantile-inverse-cdf-function/212828#212828). But from your description it is not clear if what you are trying to do has any sense (e.g. normal distribution does not seem to be good choice for cloud cover -- how could it possibly be negative? and mu and sigma are some kind of functions of some x and y -- you probably should use some kind of multivariate model etc.).

Comment: I apologize. I have historical cloud cover data that I have averaged and found the variance of. The x and y specify a point in my MATLAB data, and can be ignored. Again, my apologies for not explaining.

Answer (score 0):

***If you have good reasons*** to think that your variable follows *this/a* normal distribution (which is not the case according to Tim), what about:

*defining* your [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) as

```
density_func = @(value) (1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2))*exp(-0.5*((value - mu)^2)/sigma^2);
```

And then *computing the area under the curve* between $-\infty$ and `value=p` to get the [cumulative probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cumulative_probability&redirect=no) you want, as follows

```
cumdensities_func = @(value) quad(density_func,-inf,value);
cumdensities = cumdensities_func(p)
```

where `cumdensities` is the probability that data generated by *this* -- $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ -- gaussian process will be less than or equal to `p`.

Comment: Any question @user1187621 ?