# Can argument of a CDF be stochastic?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, cumulative-distribution-function

This question may sound very trivial and obvious, however I need to clarify this. Say we have a model:
\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta x_{t-1}+u_t
\end{equation}
where $x_{t-1}$ is stochastic and generated by the process 
\begin{equation}
x_t=\rho x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}
Now assume we want to find $P[y_t\geq 0]$. Can we express (and considering a normal CDF)
\begin{eqnarray}
P[y_t\geq 0]&=&P[\beta x_{t-1}+u_t\ge0]\\
&=&P[u_t\geq-\beta x_{t-1}]\\
&=&1-P[u_t<-\beta x_{t-1}]\\
&=&1-\Phi(-\beta x_{t-1})\\
&=&\Phi(\beta x_{t-1})?
\end{eqnarray}
As $\beta x_{t-1}$ is stochastic as opposed to a constant, would such expression be correct?

Comment: By definition, the probability of an event like "$y_t\ge 0$" is a (definite) *number.*  Thus, what you seek when you say you "want to find" its probability is an answer that is a *number,* not a random variable.  The general question in your title, though, is answered affirmatively: see [the Probability Integral Transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424169) for a salient example.

Comment: You can do the calculation conditioning on $X_{t-1} = x_{t-1}$. If you are not in reality working with conditional probabilities and really are intersted in the marginal distribution $Pr(y_t \geq 0)$ rather than $Pr(y_t \geq 0\lvert x_{t-1})$ then as Whuber says $Pr(y_t \geq 0)$ is a number but you end up with $\Phi(\beta x_{t-1})$ which is a random variable if you really are treating $x_{t-1}$ as random. My guess is you are really interested in conditional probabilities.