# How to correctly bucket data into quantiles: by index or by value?

Tags: quantiles

I've been recently involved in a discussion surrounding the assignment of individual values to n-tiles.

One way of doing it would be to rank all of the data in ascending order, dividing it into $n$ equal segments, and finding the the n-tiles. Everything that comes before the n-th index and after the (n-1)th index is said to be belonging to the n-th tile. By definition, this generates n-tile buckets that contain the same number of data points.

Another way of doing it is by value: we find the n-tiles, and then attribute any data point whose value is between the n-th tile value and the (n-1)th value to the n-th tile. In this case, the number of data points in each bucket can be different.

Let's consider the following example with quartiles:

0 0 0 0 0    0 0 1 1 1    2 3 3 4 5    5 6 7 8 8

The 1st quartile is 0, the 2nd is 1.5 (average of 1 and 2), the 3rd is 5 and the 4th is 6. Using the method by index, the first five data points belong to the 1st quartile, the next 5 data points belong to the 2nd, and so on.

However, if we were to use the "by value" method, we would have 7 data points belonging to the 1st quartile (<= 0), 3 points belonging to the 2nd quartile (<=1.5), 6 belonging to the 3rd quartile ( <= 5) and 3 belonging to the 4th quartile.
As you can see, the buckets don't contain the same number of data points.

Which method do you think is best? I will post my reasoning in the answer, but I am genuinely interested in knowing what the established way if doing this is and why.

Comment: What's the purpose of bucketing the values into groups?

Comment: Bucketing is invalid in this (and most other) context.

Comment: The purpose is to turn a continuous variable into an ordinal categorical variable.

Answer (score 1):

The "by value" method is **incorrect**, only the **by index** method is a correct way to calculate quantiles. [Quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) are related to the [quantile function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212813/help-me-understand-the-quantile-inverse-cdf-function), so recall its definition

$$
Q(p)\,=\,\inf\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R} : p \le F(x) \right\}
$$

it's the largest value $x$ such that the cumulative probability $F(x)$ is not larger than $p$. The quantile function is an inverse of the cumulative probability distribution function.

Using your example, each of the values would have the same "probability" 1/9 if using the "by value" method, so it won't be calculating the quantiles correctly.

You may also be interested in reading about different algorithms used for calculating quantiles as described by [Hyndman and Fan (1996)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222105754_Sample_Quantiles_in_Statistical_Packages).

What you are describing it's closer to [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) than calculating quantiles. In some scenarios they are useful, but they do not anyhow serve as a replacement for quantiles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "by value" method to be better than the "by index" method. When the same value sits across two quantiles, its attribution to either quantile - in the absence of an additional tie-breaking criterion for sorting on some other variable - is completely arbitrary. For example, if the values above represents scores in an exam (on a hypothetical scale of 0 to 10), and both Jack and Jane have scored 0, there is no reason why either of them should be classified as 2nd quartile, just because of how the data has been sorted. They have both scored the same score, so they should be binned together into the same quantile.