# Distribution from $\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{-T}^{T}\phi(t) ~dt = 2.$

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

Let $X$ denote a real-valued random variable with distribution function $F$ and characteristic function $\phi$. Suppose that $\phi$ satisfies the following condition:

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{-T}^{T}\phi(t) ~dt = 2.$$

What can be said about the distribution?

Attempt:

The distribution is symmetric across the $x = 0$ axis (?)

The distribution is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Without some kind of reasoning or working, your 'attempt' looks like a guess.

Answer (score 5):

[Remember](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas) that
$$
  F_X(a)-\lim_{x\uparrow a}F_X(x) = \lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^T e^{-ita}\varphi_X(t)\,dt \, . \qquad (*)
$$

If you make $a=0$ in this formula, what happens? The product rule for limits will be useful. Can you use this to say something about the distribution function at the origin?

Comment: What I can see is that if a = 0, then the $e^{-ita}$ becomes 1. As T approaches infinity, the $\frac{1}{2T}$ term becomes zero. I must be missing something.

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=2$, what can you say about $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)h(x)$?

Comment: Also, since $F_X$ is right continuous (check this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25238/how-can-i-prove-that-the-cumulative-distribution-function-is-right-continuous), the LHS of $(*)$ is the size of the jump of $F_X$ at $a$.

Comment: Suppose that $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) =L$$ and $$\lim_{x\to c} g(x) =M$$. Then

$$ \lim_{x\to c} [f(x) g(x)] = \lim_{x\to c} f(x) \lim_{x\to c} g(x) = L M $$

This is what I have for the product rule of limits. So then the equation should equal zero if we simply have L = 2 and M = 0.

Comment: And you conclude that $F_X(0)-\lim_{x\uparrow 0}F_X(x)=0$, meaning that $F_X$ is left continuous at the origin, but since $F_X$ is always righ continuous, you have that $F_X$ is continuous at the origin, which is equivalent to $\Pr(X=0)=0$.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand. So basically we know that this function (like all distribution functions) is right continuous, but we are able to ascertain that $Pr(X=0)=0$ from the given information.

Comment: Exactly. Perfect.