# Prove that a distribution is continuous at a point if and only if it has zero probability at that point

Tags: probability, distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution function $F$.
Prove that $F$ is continuous at $x = a$ if and only if $\mathbb{P}(X = a) = 0$.

Could anyone give some hints?  I am wondering where I should start with.

Comment: In the first section of my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/298434/919 (on the distinction between continuous and absolutely continuous variables) I sketch a demonstration.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. Read this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25238/how-can-i-prove-that-the-cumulative-distribution-function-is-right-continuous/25239#25239) carefully to understand how to prove the right continuity of $F$.
2. With the same style of reasoning used in that proof, try proving that $\lim_{x\uparrow a}=\Pr\{X<a\}$.
3. Since $\Pr\{X\leq a\}=\Pr\{X<a\} + \Pr\{X=a\}$, putting it all together, it follows that $F$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $\Pr\{X=a\}=0$.

Hint for the second item: pick a strictly increasing sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ with limit $a$, prove that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{X\leq x_n\} = \{X<a\}$, and use the continuity from below of the probability measure $\Pr(\;\cdot\;)$.